# custom validation error format laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel, laravel-5

I want custom validation json response for API. Right now default error message something like this

```
{"password":["The password must be at least 6 characters."],"type":["The type field is required."]}
```

I want

```
{flag:0,msg:"The password must be at least 6 characters.",data:{"password":["The password must be at least 6 characters."],"type":["The type field is required."]}}
```

And I want this format for my REST API only. How can I achieve it.

Comment: Are you using **FormRequest** or simple **Validator** ?

Comment: I use **Illuminate\Http\Request** and then **$this->validate($this->request, $rules);**

Comment: In short I want to customize MessageBag object as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution.

I chnaged my parent controller and added formatValidationErrors method. Here it is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected function formatValidationErrors(Validator $validator)
    {
        $res = $validator->errors()->all();
        if(\Request::wantsJson())
        {
            $res = ["flag" => 0,
                    "msg" => $validator->errors()->first()];
            $res['data'] = $validator->errors()->all();
        }
        return $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: For L5.5, check this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690817/laravel-5-5-validation-change-format-of-response-when-validation-fails

Answer (score 1):

The validation fires the **HttpResponseException** which we can catch and act upon

Do the following in your controller action

```
public function abc(Request $request)
{
    //using try catch to catch the validation exception thrown
    try{
       $this->validate($request, $rules);
    }catch(\Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException $e){

         //fetching the error messages 
         $messages = $e->getResponse()->getSession()->get('errors')->getMessages();

         //or you can use $messages = session()->get('errors')->getMessages();

         $messages = collect($messages);
         $content = [
             'flag' => 0,
             'data' => $messages->toArray(),
             'msg' => $messages->first()[0]
         ];

         return response()->json($content, 400);
    }

}
```

Comment: this will work but I have to add this code on every new service of my API or I can handle this exception in `Exceptions\Handler.php`. I found alternative solution please check my answere.