# Laravel 5.5 Validation change format of response when validation fails

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

In Laravel 5.4, we created a class that all our requests for validation inherited because we needed to customize our response.

```
class APIRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Response on failure
     * 
     * @param array $errors
     * @return Response
     */
    public function response(array $errors) {
        $response = new ResponseObject();

        $response->code = ResponseObject::BAD_REQUEST;
        $response->status = ResponseObject::FAILED;
        foreach ($errors as $item) {
            array_push($response->messages, $item);
        }
        return Response::json($response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

A sample request that would extend this is shown below

```
class ResultsGetTermsRequest extends APIRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'school_id' => 'required|integer',
            'student_id' => 'required|integer',
        ];
    }
}
```

And then our sample response on failure would be

```
{
    "status": "FAILED",
    "code": "400",
    "messages": [
        [
            "The school id field is required."
        ],
        [
            "The student id field is required."
        ]
    ],
    "result": []
}
```

However, this doesn't work anymore with Laravel 5.5. I noticed they replaced with response method with `failedValidation`. This however isn't returning any response when the request isn't validated. If I un-comment the print_r, it is something is returned. It seems the only line that is never executed is the return statement. What am I missing?

```
 public function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {

        $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();
        $response = new ResponseObject();

        $response->code = ResponseObject::BAD_REQUEST;
        $response->status = ResponseObject::FAILED;
        foreach ($errors as $item) {
            array_push($response->messages, $item);
        }
        //print_r($response);
        return Response::json($response);
    }
```

Comment: considering `failedValidation` returns `void` there is nothing expecting to use any return value from it ... `failedValidation` throws an exception by default

Comment: What do I need to do to send back the response? How I see it, the only other option I have is to put the validation logic inside the controllers which I am trying to avoid!

Comment: no its not the only option at all ... on failed validation it throws a `ValidationException` .. that exception can contain a response

Comment: Is that something I have to put in `Handler.php` in the `App\Exceptions` namespace? I am going to search for a way to do this but if you have any links I could use, please share.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess as per laravel [upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) guide we should return `HttpResponseException`

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $errors = $validator->errors();
        $response = new ResponseObject();

        $response->code = ResponseObject::BAD_REQUEST;
        $response->status = ResponseObject::FAILED;
        foreach ($errors as $item) {
            array_push($response->messages, $item);
        }

    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($response));
}
```

Comment: In the end, it turns out the solution is to change the  last line to `throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($response)); `

Comment: Thank you for editing the response... Let me mark this as the accepted answer. I am sure it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do this from the FormRequest classes, potentially something like this:

```
protected function buildResponse($validator)
{
    return response->json([
        'code' => ResponseObject::BAD_REQUEST,
        'status' => ResponseObject::FAILED,
        'messages' => $validator->errors()->all(),
    ]);
 }

protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw (new ValidationException($validator, $this->buildResponse($validator));
}
```

That would add that response you are building to the validation exception. When the exception handler tries to render this it will check if `response` was set and if so it will use that response you passed instead of trying to convert the ValidationException to a response itself.

If you want 'ALL' validation exceptions to end up being rendered in this format I might just do this at the exception handler level, as the exception handler already has the ability to convert these exceptions to Json, so you could alter the format in the handler itself and basically not have to make any adjustments to the default FormRequest at all.

Comment: I will try this at a later point. See accepted answer from @vijaykumar that provided the solution.

Comment: yup, its the same result, it just removes the need for having the response in the validation exception

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you are in laravel 5+ you can easily achieve this, by overriding the `invalid()` or `invalidJson()` method in the `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` file

In my case, I was developing an API and the api responses should be in a specific format, so I have added the following in the `Handler.php` file.

```
/**
     * Convert a validation exception into a JSON response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'code'    => $exception->status,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'errors'  => $this->transformErrors($exception),

        ], $exception->status);
    }

// transform the error messages,
    private function transformErrors(ValidationException $exception)
    {
        $errors = [];

        foreach ($exception->errors() as $field => $message) {
           $errors[] = [
               'field' => $field,
               'message' => $message[0],
           ];
        }

        return $errors;
    }
```

credit : [Origianal Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57396237/2693543)